# Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, plesk

I Have a vps server with PHP 5.3.3 installed ,I added a new version 5.3.28 and switch my hosting to use FastCGI with PHP-5.3.28 now i get this "Database connection error (1): The MySQL adapter 'mysql' is not available.".I beleive i miss some configuration when installing the new PHP version.any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you've also change the available adpator to `mysqli` from `mysql` — the message is saying the adapter `mysql` is not availble.

Did you remember to change your Joomla `configuration.php` file to use `mysqli`?

Open the Joomla (2.5 or 3.x) `configuration.php` file and look for the line:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql'
```

*and change it to:*

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli'
```

If it isn't already…

Comment: I have a 10 year old Joomla website that suddenly stopped working today because of this. This fixed it. Life saver!

Answer (score 3):

It simply means what it says. To fix the issue, you will need to enable the MySQLi adapter by opening your **php.ini** file and uncommenting `extension=php_mysqli.dll`. Once done, restart Apache for the changes to take effect.

There may be an option on your VPS control panel, not sure but I would suggest looking there first.

If you do not have this option, or do not have access to the **php.ini** file then you will need to contact your hosting provider

Comment: I already edited the /usr/local/lib/php.ini and uncomment extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll

Comment: @AhmedDev have you restarted apache?

Comment: i have centos 6.5 and i run this cmd using ssh service httpd restart.

Comment: @AhmedDev - Try using `apachectl restart`

Comment: I type php -v and i get this warning

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-no            n-zts-20100525/php_mysql.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_mysql.dl            l: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 2):

Open the Joomla (2.5 or 3.x) configuration.php file and look for the line:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysql'
```

and change it to:

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.. and solve using this link.. the problem is mysql lib not installed. and you should install before run again (remember reload apache)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

I hope the question solved by this link..

Comment: if you using other than Ubuntu (mac include). Use other link related to your OS. If you using WIndows, you can edit php.ini but the default on every php (win) are already make mysql on. If this not solve, try remove the apache, php, and related. try install from previous. Sometime the problem can be solve like this, as reported by my friend is not worked for older linux(!) because the linux repo remove the related resource.

Answer (score 0):

You may have many **php.ini** files, the know the right file, you can run

```
php --ini
```

The uncomment `extension=php_mysqli.dll`
Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```